# I am implementing a flow with multiple scheduled paths, how do I implement this

Tags: process-builder, salesforce-flow

The flow has multiple nodes and several scheduled paths, the original process looks like this:[image]

and this is how far I have come:

[image]

I am wondering how to link the paths without affecting actions that have only a one-time occurrence... and achieving the result that the process is serving.

Comment: did you consider using subflows?

Comment: I couldn't use subflow as each action was quiet different, I resolved it by using one decision though

Comment: great - as a service to the community, post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using a decision node with multiple actions per decision instead, given that each action is unique. Each decision was then matched to its corresponding scheduled path.

The only downside is, that when some of the decisions fall between both paths I had to repeat those, ain't seen a better way around that yet. Perhaps in the future, as I gain more experience.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting. Remember that in SF Flows, the decision conditions are checked in the order you have them (from top to bottom), and - sort of like `Case` in many languages (but not good ol' Apex!) - sometimes you can use that to your advantage and purposefully put a condition that is a subset of another one higher on the list, then the remaining items "fall through" to get picked up by the lower condition.